# Quick Launch not visible for user with permissions to certain pages and libraries

Tags: permissions, quick-launch

I have a SP 2013 site that is made up of several libraries, lists, and site pages. I have been requested to give a certain group of users access to certain components of the site. Those components are the home page, another site page, and a library. They are not allowed access to the rest of the site.
I have broken inheritance on the site pages and library and given this group of users read permission on the certain pages they are allowed to see including the home page. I have also done the same for the library. The problem is that when the user goes to the site they don't see the quick launch bar at all. The quick launch bar has numerous links including links to the pages and library that the users have access to. I thought that quick launch would be security trimmed and these users would see the links for the pages and library they have access to. However, the whole quick launch is missing along with the newsfeed. I thought that limited access permissions would give these users permissions to these pages and quick launch.

I imagine I am missing something here and that these users are missing some necessary high level permissions to access the site and thus the quick launch but I am stumped!

The other option would be to give them read permissions to the site and then break inheritance on all lists and libraries and pages and remove their access to these components of the site but I really don't want to go down this path as its a large site with numerous libraries and lists. However, I have the feeling this is the only option?!

Has anybody got some good advice on how I can tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Cameron

Answer (score 0):

```
Root Site   < == Limited Access
|
|____ Library <== your Certain Group has access to a single library
```

Your Certain Group doesn't have appropriate permission to the root site.

> Limited Access    Can view specific lists, document libraries, list
>   items, folders, or documents when given permissions.
>
> Note   You cannot assign this permission level to users or to
>   SharePoint groups. Instead, Office SharePoint Server 2007
>   automatically assigns this permission level to users and to SharePoint
>   groups when you grant them access to an object on your site that
>   requires that they have access to a higher level object on which they
>   do not have permissions. For example, if you grant users access to an
>   item in a list and they do not have access to the list itself, Office
>   SharePoint Server 2007 automatically grants them Limited Access on the
>   list, and also on the site, if needed.

[User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx)

You have the right feeling about giving them read permissions to the site and then break inheritance. That is the right way.

To remove limited access, restore inheritance or remove the higher level permission given to the item or items.

[sharepoint-permissions-worst-practices - SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/bobbyschang/sharepoint-permissions-worst-practices)